# Searching a virtual printer, that sends emails

Tags: email, pdf, smtp

I need a software, that emulates a printer, converts the printed documents to PDF/TIFF and send it via eMail to a specified address (for windows).

The virtual printer / PDF conversion is possible with a lot of PDF-converters. But I need a software, which is also able to directly mail me these PDFs. It's always the same mailaddress, and I have an SMTP server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Commercial solutions

At least a couple commercial solutions:

- [Print2Email, from Black Ice](http://www.blackice.com/Print2Email.htm), $39 single user
- [PEERNET.DRV, from Hallogram](http://www.hallogram.com/eprodriver/index.html), $119 single user

Black Ice's offering looks better - can even be configured to just send directly via SMTP, without using a local email client.

## Low-tech, DIY

Print to PDF using any of the converters mentioned to a specially named folder (eg `print-to-mail`). Then use a cron job (Linux/Mac) or Windows Task Scheduler to periodically scan `print-to-email, email it, and delete from the directory.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better / more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Added notes on a few commerical solutions that do exactly this.

Comment: Instead of a cron job, you could just use a shell script that converts to PDF and emails it immediately afterwards (and deleting the file when finished). In Windows, you could include this script as a target for the `Send To` context menu. Linux doesn't have such a context menu by default, but it can be set up with one. Though the idea of a folder where you can drop files directly into an email account is interesting. I'd use `inotify` to monitor the directory for a file to be dropped into it. This way the file gets sent the instant a file is put in that folder.

Comment: print2mail ist not perfect, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

There was a software called YAFPC (Yet Another Free PDF Composser) that did exactly what you are asking.

It's website is dead but you may find it on some mirror/archive.

Answer (score 0):

**Commercial solution:**
I think the most advanced one I've seen is Print&Share ( http://www.printandshare.info ).

This one is worth every penny.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.