# Can I Print to email by adding a email printer device?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, printing

Sorry for the vague title, I didn't know the best way to word it.

The company I work at, has Fax Machines setup as printing devices. The user will fax documents that were created in an accounting software to various remote locations. We want to change this from Fax Machines to email, and we are trying to figure out the easiest way to do this. We brought up Printing to PDF and then going into Outlook and attaching it to an email, but apparently that is too complicated.

So, is there a way we can add a device to the Printer Selections that would email the document, instead of printing it? The accounting software we use, doesn't have the option to email, only the ability to print.

Comment: Did you try googling "print to email"?

Comment: I have, and I get several links on how to print out an email in outlook.

Comment: Have you seen [this thignamajigger?](https://www.blackice.com/Print2Email.htm).. still looking. What you need is a "virtual printer" do do the work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching a virtual printer, that sends emails](https://superuser.com/questions/419545/searching-a-virtual-printer-that-sends-emails)